# How to get instance of arbitrary enums from name as String

Tags: java, list, generics, reflection, enums

Assume I have various enumerated types with a few constants each:

```
public enum MyEnum1 {

ConstantA(),
ConstantB(),
ConstantC();

}

public enum MyEnum2 {

ConstantA(),
ConstantB(),
ConstantC();

}
```

How can I get an instance of one of these enums arbitrarily from their name so that I can invoke `Enum.values()` on.

Something like:
`Enum<?> myEnumInstance = //something`

The goal is to invoke `.values()` to find and retrieve data inside the constants on said arbitrary `enum` based on user text input.

Comment: Do you mean [`Class.forName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-)?

Comment: `Class.forName(somestring).getEnumConstants()`.

Comment: Using this method I get an Object[] that I can't invoke the enum's methods on, I need to invoke the methods from the enum on the constant. Thank you for the quick answer.

Comment: If you just need to invoke `values()`, you can use `Class.forName(somestring).getEnumConstants()`. If you want this array to be of type `Enum[]`, use `Class.forName(somestring).asSubclass(Enum.class).getEnumConstants()`. If you don't know the type at compile time, you have to use the most general type.

Comment: Is there a way to specify that those enums must contain the methods? Using an Interface maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your enumerated types store data that is intended to be accessed polymorphically, then they should implement an appropriate interface. Let's say this data is a single `int`, then the enumerated types could look like this (using [IntSupplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntSupplier.html)):

```
public enum MyEnum1 implements IntSupplier {

    ConstantA(1),
    ConstantB(2),
    ConstantC(3);

    private final int number;

    private MyEnum1(int number) { this.number = number; }
    public int getAsInt() { return number; }
}
```

Then you can leverage that interface to get the list of the enumerated values (constants) that is properly typed:

```
IntSupplier[] myEnums = Class.forName("MyEnum1")
            .asSubclass(IntSupplier.class)
            .getEnumConstants();
```

And use that to get the values:

```
for(IntSupplier value : myEnums) {
        System.out.println(value.getAsInt());
}
```

Comment: Does the interface need to be a `@FunctionalInterface`?